# Get Azure pipeline variable value dynamically

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have defined a variable for my pipeline that looks like this

```
My Username-key
```

with some value that is not important. `My Username` here is the name for my account, and is equal to the result of `$(build.QueuedBy)`.

I want to reference it inside my task that looks like this:

```yaml
- task: PowerShell@2 #CmdLine@2 
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: |
      $key= "$(build.QueuedBy)".replace(" ","") + '-KEY'
      echo $key | Invoke-Expression
```

What I get is an error that looks like this:

```
Invoke-Expression : The term 'MyUsername-KEY' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
...
```

How can I dynamically get the value of the variable in the example above in the same way that I could get it if I directly executed

```
echo $(MyUsername-KEY)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable expressions in form of `$(MyUsername-KEY)` are evaluated *before* the script is executed. So there's no way to use them in that form dynamically. But you can take advantage of the fact that pipeline variable are also exposed as [env variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#access-variables-through-the-environment). You can get the value of environment variable dynamically like this:

```
(get-item "env:$key").value
```

If you need to debug it, you can get a list of all env variables:

```
ls env:
```